# UIimageview zoom full image in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uiimageview, zooming, uigesturerecognizer

Have one Imageview in xib. That xib file created in one view class.

Add that xib file in top of the header in one viewcontroller.

Now the user Click that imageview that image want to show full screen in device[image]. After touch the image means become small size (like zoom and zoom out). Saw many link saw it, but they add the scrollview and zoom the images. With out add the scrollview how to make full screen image in swift.

[or any other way to zoom in zoom out in swift] Help me thanx advance.

Comment: What's the question? could you elaborate?

Comment: Here profile image is there,  click that profile image it want zoom full image(like zoom in zoom out).